# VBA function works on Windows Excel but not Mac Excel

Tags: macos, worksheet-function, vba

On a *Windows* version of *Excel* this displays the address of the cell where the name resides.

On *Ma*c it returns the result of the **IfError** argument.

[image]

The VBA code for the "search address" function is:

```
Function searchaddress(searchrange As Range, searchvalue As Range)
     searchaddress = searchrange.Find(searchvalue).Address(False, False)
End Function
```

Why would this not be working in Mac Excel?

Comment: Not sure if it's a Osx problem. I tried to copy your example on win10 excel 2010, and I get "not working" as well.
Isn't the function supposed to be `=IFERROR(searchaddress($A$1:$C$3;E2);"Not working")` ?

Comment: Unless information is a namerange... then nevermind.

Comment: Where is the function searchaddress() defined?  I'm guessing it's either defined in a Macro module in the current workbook, or possibly in the Personal Workbook.   So, as to why it's not working, possibly macros are disabled on your Mac, or if you think it's in the Personal Workbook, maybe it's in the "wrong" one.  MS keeps changing the location where that should be stored on the Mac...